# how to convert json in array in php

Tags: php, json

I just learned php, please help
i have a json 
I don't know if this json is valid or not, then how do I enable json to an array

```
"[{id_service\":\"3\",\"reference_number\":\"\",\"tracking_number\":\"RJC-0000-0001\",\"kd_inbound\":\"INB-1000-0001\",\"tgl_inbound\":\"2019-11-08 00:00:00\",\"status_inb\":\"1\"},{\"id_service\":\"3\",\"reference_number\":\"\",\"kd_outbag\":\"BAG-1468-0001\",\"tanggal_outbag\":\"2019-11-08 00:00:00\",\"status_outbag\":\"1\"},{\"id_service\":\"3\",\"reference_number\":\"\",\"kd_outbound\":\"OTB-1826-0001\",\"tgl_outbound\":\"2019-11-08 14:04:00\",\"status_otb\":\"1\"},{\"id_service\":\"3\",\"reference_number\":\"\",\"tracking_number\":\"RJC-0000-0001\",\"kd_indes\":\"INB-DES-56730001\",\"tgl_indes\":\"2019-11-08 14:07:30\",\"status_indes\":\"1\"},{\"id_service\":\"3\",\"reference_number\":\"\",\"tracking_number\":\"RJC-0000-0001\",\"tgl_status\":\"2019-11-07 17:06:43\",\"status\":\"Consignee Unknown\"},{\"id_service\":\"3\",\"reference_number\":\"\",\"tracking_number\":\"RJC-0000-0001\",\"tgl_status\":\"2019-11-08 10:29:07\",\"status\":\"Closed\"}]"
```

how to convert json to array

this my code

```
public function awb_get() {
    $id = $this->get('tracking_number');
    $arr= array(      
      $this->M_tarif->tampil_status_inbound($id),
      $this->M_tarif->tampil_status_otboundbag($id),
      $this->M_tarif->tampil_status_otboundori($id),
      $this->M_tarif->tampil_status_indes($id)
  );


    $result = str_replace(array('[',']','\n'), '',htmlspecialchars(json_encode($arr), ENT_NOQUOTES));
    $str = preg_replace("#(/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|([\s\t]//.*)|(^//.*)#", '', $result);
    $json = '[';
    $json .= substr($str, 2,-1); 
    $json .= ']';
    $jsonData = preg_replace("/,(?!.*,)/", "", $json);
    $this->response($jsonData, 200);
}
```

how to replace json properly so output like this

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id_service] => 3
        [reference_number] => 
        [tracking_number] => RJC-0000-0001
        [kd_inbound] => INB-1000-0001
        [tgl_inbound] => 2019-11-07 00:00:00
        [status_inb] => 1
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id_service] => 3
        [reference_number] => 
        [kd_outbag] => BAG-1468-0002
        [tanggal_outbag] => 2019-11-07 00:00:00
        [status_outbag] => 1
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id_service] => 3
        [reference_number] => 
        [kd_outbound] => OTB-1826-0001
        [tgl_outbound] => 2019-11-07 17:04:49
        [status_otb] => 1
    )
```

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of what $arr looks like? Just datadump/echo it. Once you do that comment back and ill help you debug this and clean it up.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BWhiFbzw

Comment: `json_encode()` returns valid JSON. Literally everything you do after than corrupts it further and further. You should simply explain what you want done with the data, and why.

Answer (score 0):

This is just JSON encoded as a JSON string. So just [decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode) it twice.

```
$data = '"[{\"id_service\":\"3\",\"reference_number\":\"\",\"tracking_number\":\"RJC-0000-0001\",\"kd_inbound\":\"INB-1000-0001\",\"tgl_inbound\":\"2019-11-08 00:00:00\",\"status_inb\":\"1\"},{\"id_service\":\"3\",\"reference_number\":\"\",\"kd_outbag\":\"BAG-1468-0001\",\"tanggal_outbag\":\"2019-11-08 00:00:00\",\"status_outbag\":\"1\"},{\"id_service\":\"3\",\"reference_number\":\"\",\"kd_outbound\":\"OTB-1826-0001\",\"tgl_outbound\":\"2019-11-08 14:04:00\",\"status_otb\":\"1\"},{\"id_service\":\"3\",\"reference_number\":\"\",\"tracking_number\":\"RJC-0000-0001\",\"kd_indes\":\"INB-DES-56730001\",\"tgl_indes\":\"2019-11-08 14:07:30\",\"status_indes\":\"1\"},{\"id_service\":\"3\",\"reference_number\":\"\",\"tracking_number\":\"RJC-0000-0001\",\"tgl_status\":\"2019-11-07 17:06:43\",\"status\":\"Consignee Unknown\"},{\"id_service\":\"3\",\"reference_number\":\"\",\"tracking_number\":\"RJC-0000-0001\",\"tgl_status\":\"2019-11-08 10:29:07\",\"status\":\"Closed\"}]"';
$json = json_decode($data);
$array = json_decode($json);
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score -1):

To check whether `JSON` is valid:

```
function isJson($string) {
   json_decode($string);
   return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
}
```

And to parse `JSON` into `array` :

```
json_decode($string, true);
```

Update:

To remove `\` from your string, use:

```
stripslashes($string);
```

Comment: this json valid, how to remove character \ \ \ \ in json ?

Comment: @yudafajar use `stripslashes()` to remove `\` from string